# how to set app pool identity for ASP.NET app deployed to aws elastic beanstalk

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

How can you tell AWS-EB the desired AppPool identity for an ASP.NET web app running in IIS? In the AWS Beanstalk Deploy wizard I don't see this option like you would if deploying straight to IIS or when changing it manually in IIS. Obviously once deployed you can change it in the EC2 instance, but that doesn't help the "xcopy deploy" story of using EB.

Comment: I think this article might help [link](https://jaredmeredith.wordpress.com/2017/07/03/aws-elastic-beanstalk-ebextensions-update-the-iis-app-pool-using-commands-to-another-app-pool-identity/)

Comment: @demonicdaron Yes, I believe that will work perfectly! Please put that as an answer and I'll accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use Elastic Beanstalk [ebextensions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/ebextensions.html) for this.
Ebextensions allow you to run custom scripts when deploying code.

The process is pretty simple:

1. You create a folder in your project (at root level) called
   ".ebextensions".
2. Create a configuration file in the yaml format.
   That file will be executed when you deploy your code and is the
   place where you can change the application pool identity.
3. Deploy your code.

[This article](https://jaredmeredith.wordpress.com/2017/07/03/aws-elastic-beanstalk-ebextensions-update-the-iis-app-pool-using-commands-to-another-app-pool-identity/) has an example configuration file to change the application pool identity and more details on how to add ebextensions in your project.

Hope this helps!